# How do I validate Touch_ID or Face_ID in MacBook at certain point of time in my application

Tags: java, ios, touch-id, face-id

I have a scenario where I have to provide a security(like Face_ID or Touch_ID) in BacBook while proceeding further in my application.

I'm not finding any solution on google.

No Code

Comment: Could you clarify your question - do you want to use TouchID on macOS or TouchID/FaceID on an iOS device - you have tagged the latter but you are asking about the former.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to coding. Could you please tell me can we validate Touch_ID on macOS on click of button in my application and then proceed further. Please forgive me if I'm asking wrong question.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication

Comment: Thanks Paulw11 for your quick reply, I think the link which you have provided is only for MacOS or IOS apps, I want to do it in JAVA web application. Is it possible please reply back.

Comment: It would help if you could clarify your question. What do you mean by a java web app?  A java application running on the Mac - if so, then you should be able to use JNI to call the local authentication framework. If you mean something running in the browser then I don't believe that there is any biometric authentication available.

Comment: Hi Paulw11, I have created a Java application to do a digital signing on PDF and the same application is running in macOS, whenever I press digital signature button it directly doing signing. So in that case i have to provide a authentication, whenever user press on button I have to do LocalAuthentication then proceed further.

Comment: Then you will need to look into JNI to call the local authentication framework.

Answer (score 0):

1. Edit the file /etc/pam.d/sudo
2. add this in your file.

`auth       sufficient     pam_tid.so`

3. Iterm2 has more settings to be add.

This is for touchID in console.